# How to setdiff two vectors using substring

Tags: r, vector

traditionally when working with vectors setdiff works if you want to compare exact values between vectors:

```
superset <- c("price", "color", "size")
subset <- c("color", "price")
length(setdiff(superset, subset)) == 0
```

but i want to match based on substring:

```
superset <- c("price", "colorB", "colorC", "size")
length(setdiff(superset, c("color")) == 0 # wishful thinking
length(setdiff(superset, c("color", "not_color")) == 1 # wishful thinking
```

i know i can brute for with lapply and grepl. i didn't know if there was a better way.

Comment: Starting with `superset <- c("price", "colorB", "colorC", "size")` and then using `supserset[!grepl("color",superset)]` results in "price" and "size". The "colorB" and "colorC" are removed.

Comment: so that is suggesting a combination of lappy and grepl right? (because subset can have multiple values)

Comment: If you don't have too many values then you can do `superset[!grepl("color",superset) & !grepl("size",superset)]`. That will remove any string that has "color" and "size". If you have dozens of values then lapply may be better. Also if your values are consistent, like "colorA", "colorB", "colorC", .... , "colorZ" then you could do superset[!(substr(superset,1,5) == "color")] to get rid of all colors.